# Error while doing sort operation in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting

```
x=['Hello', 90, 8.9999, 4.6, 'DOG', 'CAT', 1]
x.reverse()

x
Out[109]: ['Hello', 90, 8.9999, 4.6, 'DOG', 'CAT', 1]

x.sort()
```

Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-110-42dad5a67ac3>", line 1, in <module>
  x.sort()

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'
```

why I am getting this error?

Comment: Your list is of mixed type. The less than comparison is failing when it tries to compare two elements which cannot be compared. What order were you expecting! Is 'DOG' before or after 90?

Comment: did you read the typeerror message?

Comment: You can not sort 2 different types. For e.g. which one is greater, an integer 5 or a string "Hello" ?

Comment: If this were real, your list would have been reversed after you called `x.reverse()`.

Comment: Can we not define a rule?

Comment: Yes you can define a rule, that's what the `key` argument in `sort` (or sorted) is for.  What rule do you want?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the error, you can compare only things of the same `type`. You could go and try to modify the int/float/str types to be able to do such comparison, but messing with internal properties of built in types is a very bad idea.

What you can do, is to cast numbers to strings and then do sort. This will perform a lexicographically sort.

```
a = ['Hello', 90, 8.9999, 4.6, 'DOG', 'CAT', 1]
a_str = [str(e) for e in a]
a_str.sort()
a_str
```

will produce `['1', '4.6', '8.9999', '90', 'CAT', 'DOG', 'Hello']`

Comment: and if one of the integer values was 10?

Comment: It'll be placed second, that's what lexicographical order does. The OP does not specify which "rule" he want's to use.

Comment: Exactly, but we don't know the rule that the OP requires.

Comment: Thanks for the solution